# Multiple arrays merging issue

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays

**First array**

```
array(
    [0] => +970
    [1] => +971
    [2] => +972
)
```

**And Second array**

```
array(
    [0] => 465465454
    [1] => 321321355
    [2] => 987946546
)
```

I want to merge them like this

```
array(
    [+970] => 465465454
    [+971] => 321321355
    [+972] => 987946546
)
```

I try with `array_merge` but this gives me the result that I didn't want e.g.

```
$busi_code  = $page1_data->business_code; //array
$busi_num  = $page1_data->business_number; //array

$business_phone_numbers = array_merge($busi_code, $busi_num);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($business_phone_numbers);
echo '</pre>';
```

And its result is

```
[0] => +970
[1] => +971
[2] => +972
[3] => 465465454
[4] => 321321355
[5] => 987946546
```

So please guide me how can I achieve my required result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), rather than `array_merge`:

> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

```
$business_phone_numbers = array_combine($busi_code, $busi_num);
```

See https://eval.in/954799

Answer (score 4):

This is job for `array_combine` function:

```
$business_phone_numbers = array_combine($busi_code, $busi_num);
```

**DOCS:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score -1):

You must use array_combine.

Try this:

```
$a = array(
0 => +970,
1 => +971,
2 => +972);

$b = array(
0 => 465465454,
1 => 321321355,
2 => 987946546);

$r = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($r);
```

Comment: Your $b array is already the two arrays combined, also this has been answered over 10 minutes ago.